# JQuery keeping focus on div

Tags: jquery, html

I've got a button `updateLogButton` when clicked shows the div and when clicked again hides it. I've got this part working. Only problem is everytime the button is clicked focus is moved to the beginning of the page instead of focusing on the content in the div.

JQuery code:

```
    //hide div on page load
$('#updateLogText').hide();

$('#updateLogButton').click(function() {

    if ($('#updateLogText').is(':visible')){

        //hide div if content is visible
        $('#updateLogText').fadeOut();

    }else{

        $('#updateLogText').fadeIn();       
    }

});
```

HTML code:

```
<tr>
    <td><a href="#"  id="updateLogButton">Update Log</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3" >
        <div id="updateLogText" style="width:100%;">
            <?php echo $data['updates']; ?>
        </div>

    </td>
</tr>
```

Anybody know how this can be achieved? i have looked at the JQuery documentation and tried:

```
$("#updateLogText").focus();
$("#updateLogText").attr("tabindex",-1).focus();
```

The above doesn't work..

Comment: Closing and raising as a more appropriate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795566/how-to-stop-link-button-refreshing-the-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the  `<a href="#"` remove `#` or the `href` attribute itself

Write it as -

```
<a id="updateLogButton">Update Log</a>
```

css -

```
a{ cursor: pointer; }
```

Comment: The above works except that its a link button so I do need the pointer to appear. Any way I can have the best of both worlds? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this I think  you should use `fadeToggle()` instead of checking div is visible or not
and after that set focus

```
    //hide div on page load
$('#updateLogText').hide();

$('#updateLogButton').click(function() {

          $('#updateLogText').fadeToggle();       
          $('#updateLogText').focus();       
    }

);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cF4Bb/5/

Answer (score 0):

Ud below line it will work you have not given -1 in quotes that why focus in not comming

$("#updateLogText").attr("tabindex",-1).focus();