# How to stop link button refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code I'm using a link button called `updateLogButton` which shows/hides a div. Because I use a link button everytime its clicked focus is moved to the beginning of the page. How can I stop this default behaviour?

Jquery snippet:

```
$('#updateLogText').hide();

$('#updateLogButton').click(function() {

    if ($('#updateLogText').is(':visible')){

        //hide div if content is visible
        $('#updateLogText').fadeOut();

    }else{

        $('#updateLogText').fadeIn();       
    }

});
```

HTML code:

```
<tr>
    <td><a href="#"  id="updateLogButton">Update Log</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3" >
        <div id="updateLogText" style="width:100%;">
            <?php echo $data['updates']; ?>
        </div>

    </td>
</tr>
```

**EDIT:**
example of what i mean: http://jsfiddle.net/cF4Bb/7/

Comment: One way to achieve that is to remove `href` from a tag.

Comment: @Dev that completely removes the `a` functionality (hover colors etc.) in some browsers, so I guess that's not an option.

Comment: @Rune: If you don't want redirection, there shouldn't be any issue.

Comment: @Dev: removing the href tag doesn't give me the 'visual pointer' for the link button.

Comment: @greenpool: You can get that by CSS: `cursor:pointer;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To prevent the default action when the link is clicked you can return false from the click handler or call `event.preventDefault` where event is the event object passed to the click handler.

```
$('#updateLogText').hide();

$('#updateLogButton').click(function(event) {

    if ($('#updateLogText').is(':visible')){

        //hide div if content is visible
        $('#updateLogText').fadeOut();

    }else{

        $('#updateLogText').fadeIn();       
    }
    event.preventDefault();
    //or return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Add return false

```
$('#updateLogButton').click(function() {

    if ($('#updateLogText').is(':visible')){

        //hide div if content is visible
        $('#updateLogText').fadeOut();

    }else{

        $('#updateLogText').fadeIn();       
    }

     return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try changing your `href` to:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="updateLogButton">Update Log</a>
```

Comment: Even just "javascript:" will do! Great tip!

Answer (score 0):

Return false from the one click event

```
$('#updateLogText').hide();

$('#updateLogButton').click(function() {

    if ($('#updateLogText').is(':visible')){

       //hide div if content is visible
        $('#updateLogText').fadeOut();

    }else{

        $('#updateLogText').fadeIn();       
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the href="#" from

```
<td><a **href="#"** id="updateLogButton">Update Log</a></td>
```

to

```
<td><a id="updateLogButton">Update Log</a></td>
```

note that this may remove the 'hyperlink' like text; which you can re-apply using css.

[EDIT: ADDED]
Alternatively you can use LinkButton instead as follows:

```
<asp:LinkButton id="btnLink" Text="Update Log" **onclick**="javascript:ShowHide(); return false;"/>
```

You will have to write your own javascript function. **Note: can't remember on top of my head whether it onclick or onclientclick but you get the idea.

Comment: What's with this ASP stuff? Also this prevents the <A> from getting a tabindex.